# How to loop in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.7

I have the following sample dictoinary within a dictionary  , how can i loop and show key/values only  within the data field. When i run the below I am getting follwoing error. Not sure what i am doing wrong. Any advise please.

```
    in1 = {
    "data": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
        "bio": "This is my bio",
        "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
        "counts": {
            "media": 1320,
            "follows": 420,
            "followed_by": 3410
        }
}}
print(in1['data']['id'])

for k , v in in1.items():

    print("\n RAW DATA:" + k)
    u_info = v['username'] + ' ' + v['full_name']
    print("Thanks for the info : " + u_info)

    for ke,v1 in v.items():
        print("Keys ", ke['website'])
        print("Keys ", ke['counts'])
```

Error i am getting is

```
python3 dictionary_example.py
1574083

 RAW DATA:data
Thanks for the info : snoopdogg Snoop Dogg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dictionary_example.py", line 24, in <module>
    print("Keys ", ke['website'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Please specify what error you are getting.

Comment: sorry the error is :python3 dictionary_example.py
1574083

 RAW DATA:data
Thanks for the info : snoopdogg Snoop Dogg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dictionary_example.py", line 24, in <module>
    print("Keys ", ke['website'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0):

you are printing `u_info` inside quotes that causing the problem.
In your code you are trying to use key `k1` as a dictionary but it is string.
If you want  to print `website` and `counts` values there is no need to use the for loop you can directly use `v['website']` and `v['counts']`.

```
in1 = {
    "data": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
        "bio": "This is my bio",
        "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
        "counts": {
            "media": 1320,
            "follows": 420,
            "followed_by": 3410
        }
}}

print(in1['data']['id'])

for k , v in in1.items():
    print("\n RAW DATA:" + k)
    u_info = v['username'] + ' ' + v['full_name']
    print("\t" + u_info)

    print("Keys ", v['website'])
    print("Keys ", v['counts'])
```

Answer (score 0):

like @Raju answer, you can get the value of `['website']` and `['counts']` without loop, because its only single dictionary (based on your question).

just try :

`print(in1['data']['id'])
 print(in1['data']['website'])
 print(in1['data']['counts'])`